# 'Series' object has no attribute 'columns' when trying to plot a scatter matrix in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, jupyter-notebook, scatter

Hi I am new to python and working with jupyter notebook, so any help would be greatly appreciated!.

I am having trouble plotting a scatter matrix.
I have imported my csv file and I have a column with 'Names' of drugs. So I want to get how many times this drug occurs so I use

```
name = Crimes['drug name'].value_counts()
name
```

This returns how many times a specific drug has been called as 'drug name' is the column in my csv file

I have tried to plot a scatter matrix like so:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas.plotting import scatter_matrix
scatter_matrix(name, alpha=0.2, figsize=(6, 6), diagonal='kde')
```

However I am getting an error 'Series' object has no attribute 'columns'

Does anyone know how I can fix this issue?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass  [pandas.core.series.Series](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.html#pandas.Series) to scatter_matrix function because it accepts only Dataframes with morethan one column(This is not in documents). Please read the documentation. Screenshot for reference.[image: screen shot for reference.]
Also the Scatter_plot is used to represent the distributions of columns comparing with all other columns check the reference: [Pandas scatterplot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#scatter-matrix-plot).
The error is due to it is accessing the columns in the dataframe where as you are using Series which do not have columns that is the main reason.
These are the possible reasons. Correct me if wrong.

Comment: @Katie for better understanding of data use bar chart. Since the drug name is categorical type it is good to use bar chart to get more insights about data.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print scatter_matrix with only one column of data

`scatter_matrix(data_frame[['column_name']])`

Answer (score 0):

Matplotlib had a scatterfunction, ”https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html” which i would suggest!